# Recombinate two complex attributes into new object

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I want to recombine a (complex) member attribute of two agents and put it in a new agent. It's a vector of numbers, every second value is taken from agent1, the rest from agent2. The problem is, I want to be able to exchange the implementation of my `numberList`, maybe another `numberListInt2` using integers or like in my example using floats:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class NumberList {
};

class NumberListInt : public NumberList {
    vector<int>  number_list {1,2,3};
};

class NumberListFloat : public NumberList {
    vector<float>  number_list  {1.2f,2.5f,30.0f};
};

class Agent {
    NumberList* numbers;
    public:
        Agent();
        Agent(NumberList* numbers) {
            numbers = numberList*
        }
        ~Agent() {
            delete numbers;
        }
        NumberList* recombine(Agent& other) {
            NumberList* new_number_list;
            if(true) // a boolean config value
                new_number_list = new NumberListInt();
            else
                new_number_list = new NumberListFloat();

            for(unsigned int i=0;i<3;i++) {
                if(i%2)
                    new_number_list[i] = other.get_number_list()[i];
                else
                    new_number_list[i] = numbers[i];
            }
            return new_number_list;
        }

        NumberList* get_number_list() {
            return numbers;
        }
};

int main ()
{
    Agent agent;
    Agent agent2;
    Agent agent3(agent.recombine(agent2));
    return 0;
}
```

My questions:

1. How to implement the operator `[]` of `NumberList`?
2. Is there a better way than using a pointer for the polymorphism?
3. Do I free the memory correctly?

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The problem is that `operator[]` shall return a reference to an item of the `NumberList`.  But you don't know the type of the numbers, when you're in the parent class. So you won't be able to define this operator in a polymorphic manner (unless you define somehow a polymorphic item).
2. To benefit from polymorphism you have to use references or pointers.  In your case the pointers are a good alternative.  However you have to clarify their use in the constructors. I assume that the copy constructor should copy the object and not reuse the list of the original agent.
3. No, because you have not defined a virtual destructor for `NumberList`.  And when you `recombine()` you return a newly allocated list.  So the caller has to delete the returned object.  That's very dangerous:  if he forget, memory will leak.  You'd better consider opting for `shared_ptr` to avoid leaking.
4. It's not clear if you need dynamic change of the `NumberList` type at runtime.  If you don't, a safer approach would be to use templates

With templates it would look like:

```
template <class T>
class NumberList {
    vector<T>  number_list;
    T& operator[] (size_t i) { return numberlist[i]; }  // may be add boundary check ?
};

template <class T> 
class Agent {
    NumberList<T> numbers;  // No more pointer, but directly the object 
    .... 
};
```

Comment: I solved it now creating a specific function for every NumberList. Not the most polymorphic way, but it works ;)